# issue with the regular expression pattern for ALTER TABLE commands with ADD, ALTER, or DROP column clauses

Tags: python

have set up a trigger that detects any Data Definition Language (DDL) changes made to a database and logs these changes into a table. The table captures details such as the Database Name, Table Name, Login Name, SQL Command, Schema Name, and Audit Date Time. Additionally, I have developed a Python script that extracts the meaning from the SQL Command column using regular expressions and transfers this information to a destination table. The destination table captures details such as the Database, Schema, Table, and Columns.

why the script

```
alter_pattern =r'^(alter)\s+(TABLE)\s+(\[?(?P<database>[^\]\.\s]+)?\]?\.)?\[?(?P<schema>[^\]\.\s]+)?\]?\.(?P<table>[^\]\.\s]+)\s+(ADD|ALTER|DROP)\s+(?P<columns>[^\)]+)\)'  
for sql_command in test:
    alter_match = re.match(alter_pattern, sql_command, re.IGNORECASE)
    if alter_match:
        database = alter_match.group('database') or database
        schema = alter_match.group('schema') 
        table = alter_match.group('table')
        column_str = alter_match.group('columns')
        column = [col.strip() for col in column_str.split(',')]
        data.append({'database': database, 'schema': schema, 'table': table, 'columns': column,'EVENT':'alter'})

cnxn.close()
```

detects only information from the sqlcommand

```
alter table dbo.test ADD adresse_rue VARCHAR(255)
```

and the sertie test contains several sqlcommant like

```
3     alter table dbo.test ADD adresse_rue VARCHAR(255)
6     alter table  [stg].[MetaChatbot] add test1 CHA...
7     alter table [stg].[MetaChatbot] add test2 char...
8     alter table [stg].[MetaChatbot] add test3 char...
33    alter table [stg].[MetaChatbot] add hhhhhh var...
39        alter table [stg].[test4] add rue varchar(50)
60           alter table [dbo].[yyyel] add nnnnnnnn int
62         alter table [dbo].[yyyel] ADD nnnnnHHnnn int
63           alter table dbo.yyyel ADD nnnttnnHHnnn int
64         alter table dbo.yyyel ADD nnnttjjnnHHnnn INT
68            alter table [stg].[chat] add colonne3 int
71        alter table [stg].[chat3] add colonne3333 int
72    alter table  [stg].[MetaChatbot]add colonne333...
73       alter table [dbo].[yyyel] add colonnekkkkk int
74              alter table dbo.yyyel ADD testfinal INT
Name: SQLCommand, dtype: object)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why only the first line matches (I assume that the numbers and following 4 spaces, or 5 for single-digit numbers, are not actually part of the lines to be matched):

- The pattern requires that there are no leading spaces in front of the `alter` keyword.
- The `table` capturing group does not allow table names which contain a `]` character.
- The pattern requires that there is a `)` character at the end of the `columns` capturing group (not included in the group).